# Calculating SUM from a column data that comes from two sources

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am hoping someone can help me with this query.  I am trying to SUM the rate based on the Match ID; however, I could get that Match ID from one of two places or it could be NULL.  You can see from the example below that what is happening is that the NULL line items are being included in the f.matchID calculation.  How can I have those NULL lines calculate by themselves and not be included in either the f.matchID or g.matchID sums?  Any help you can provide would be appreciated.  Thanks!!

```
SELECT 
    c.[Corp]
   ,b.[FGN_Key]
   ,b.[ACP_Key]
   ,case when f.[matchid] is null then g.[matchid] else f.[matchid] end "MatchID"
   ,case when f.[RuleBaseId] is null then g.[RuleBaseId] else f.[RuleBaseId] end "RuleID"
   ,case when f.[Pass] is null then g.[Pass] else f.[Pass] end  "Pass"
   ,isnull(e.[DWELL],'') "Dwell"
   ,isnull(d.[DCNT],'') "CDU"
   ,b.[Service]
   ,c.[TrueRateCode]
   ,b.[Retail_Rate]
   --,sum(b.[Retail_Rate]) over (partition by f.[matchid]) 
   ,case when f.[matchid] is null then sum(b.[Retail_Rate]) over (partition by g.[matchid]) else sum(b.[Retail_Rate]) over (partition by f.[matchid]) end "Total by Combo"
   --,c.[TrueCodeLength]
   ,c.[RateCnt]
   ,c.[outlet_no]
   ,cast([StartDate] as date) "StartDate"
   ,cast([StopDate] as date) "StopDate"
   ,c.[PromoCode]
   ,cast([DiscountStrtDate] as date) "DiscStartDate"
   --,c.[T30_Rate]
   --,c.[XTrailer_Amt]
   ,isnull(c.[non_std_flag],'') non_std_flag
   ,c.[ReferenceNumber]
FROM 
   [trn].[rate_compare_foreign] b
   left join [site].[tmp_Foreign_Rate_Codes] c on b.ACP_Key = c.[CSGSubscriber] and b.[service] = c.[FullServCode]
   left join [amdocs7_6].[CF000T] d on c.[Corp] = d.[Corp] and c.[House] = d.[House] and c.[Cust] = d.[Cust] and [DCNT] = '6'
   left join [amdocs7_6].[HF000T] e on c.[Corp] = e.[Corp] and c.[House] = e.[House] and c.[Cust] = e.[Cust] and e.[DWELL] in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','7','8','A','B','C','D','F','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','W')
   left join [ruleng].[breadcrumb] f on c.[corp] = f.[prtnid] and c.[house]+c.[cust] = f.[group0] and c.[id] = f.[factid]
   left join [ruleng].[breadcrumb_item_lob] g on c.[corp] = g.[prtnid] and c.[house]+c.[cust] = g.[group0] and c.[id] = g.[factid]
WHERE 
   ACP_Key = @key
   and [Service] <> 'STMT'
ORDER BY
   f.[matchid]
   ,g.[matchid] 
   ,f.[RuleBaseId]
   ,g.[RuleBaseId]
   ,b.[Service]
```

I am unable to attach a picture because I don't enough points (whatever that means) so I will just have to try to give you an example verbally.

Match ID - NULL
Rate - -5.00
Current Sum Total - 34.99 (s/be -5.00)

f.Match ID - 1
Rate(s) - 19.96, 25.03, -5.00
Current Sun Total - 39.99 (s/be 39.99)

f.Match ID - 2
Rate - 0.00
Current Sun Total - 0.00 (s/be 0.00)

g.Match ID - 3
Rate - 10.00
Current Sun Total - 10.00 (s/be 10.00)

Comment: Is the problem that in addition to being NULL in your select due to outer joins, f.matchid and / or g.matchid can also be NULL in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a sub-query for each sum, just the column for the sum and the id to group the records.
After you test your sum and know it is correct, use the query as a sub-query in your complete query. This will isolate the sum for each table.
The sum needs the records to be grouped by the correct information.